# PLC communication error using S7NetPlus library in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, ethernet, plc, modbus-tcp

I am developing a windows forms application which will communicate with the Siemens S7-1200 PLC for real accessing real time data from PLC and sending data to PLC. The connection and real time communication is all working fine. But I'm facing issues when

1. Closing the connection to PLC.
2. Ethernet cable is disconnected
3. The PLC is powered off

1 . I have used Plc.close() method in the form.closed event. But the connection is not getting closed ,
instead throwing PLC disconnection error.

2 & 3. I expected same behavior but it is throwing different errors.
When ethernet cable was disconnected either at application side or PLC side, the ethernet socket
exception is thrown.
When the PLC power was turned off the program was still trying to write data to the PLC for some
time and then showed the ethernet socket error happened.

Can anyone help me with how to handle these errors?

Comment: _"Can anyone help me with how to handle these errors?"_ - what's the desired behavior? At Protocol Level, you cannot distinguish if the device has been powered off or the Layer 0 link is broken (cable disconnected).

Comment: _"...instead throwing PLC disconnection error"_ - Please add a stacktrace and code.

Comment: Hi @Fildor Desired behavior is close the application without throwing s7.Net socket error when the Form.closed error is called.

Comment: @Fildor  
in case 2 and 3: It should suspend all the functions related to the PLC read and write. and should wait for the Ethernet connection to reconnect/ or the PLC to power On.

Comment: _" It should suspend all the functions related to the PLC read and write. and should wait for the Ethernet connection to reconnect/ or the PLC to power On"_ Well, that's a lot. You could use a try/catch to disable some functions on exception. That's the easy-part. "Waiting" for reconnection or power up is somewhat tricky. You really only know if it is up and running if you _can_ establish a working connection. So, if you have no other means of detection, you're stuck with wait-and-retry.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on [s7netplus](https://github.com/S7NetPlus/s7netplus/blob/develop/S7.Net/PLC.cs) repository on Github the PLC class is implementig IDisposeable. In your question there is no code but if you are calling the PLC class with a using statment:

```cs
using(Plc plc = new PLC(...) {
  // Do some actions
}
```

the Close() method is called after the end of the using block (Dispose). So if you are trying to call the Close() method again an exception occurs.

If it is possible, please provide a code example.